# How to reverse Match for cell containing string Excel 2010

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

From column O I would like to lookup column A, starting from my current row, to find the first cell with a comma. Goal is to have the correct date in each row.
Table I'm working in https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJcBC.png

```
=MATCH("*"&","&"*",$A$1:INDIRECT("A" & ROW()),0)
```

If I could just run it backwards that be great but I'm not finding a way that works with wildcards or contains in excel 2010. My other thought was to make an a range based off position, invert it, find the index and do length - index but I'm not sure how I would go about that. I'm pretty new to excel so any help would be apricated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`=MAX(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(",",A1:INDEX(A:A,ROW()))),ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A,ROW())),))`

Instead of MATCH which looks from top to bottom and returns the first match, use MAX to return the max row number of the cell containing `,`. You can use either FIND or SEARCH.

If you wrap it in INDEX you get your value:

`=INDEX(A:A,MAX(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(",",A1:INDEX(A:A,ROW()))),ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A,ROW())),)))`

It might require to be entered with `ctrl+shift+enter`. I'm unable to test it in older Excel version.

Edit for further explanation of how it works:

`A1:INDEX(A:A,ROW())` is to be read as cell `A1` up to the current row in column A. So if you're at row # 10 it would equal `A1:A10`.
Wrapping that range in `FIND` returns the position of the character you try to find.
If given character is not found in  the cell it returns error #N/A.

So if you have row 1 and 9 containing `,` in this case, it returns an array of numbers for the hits and errors for the non-hits, for instance `{2,#N/A,#N/A,#N/A,#N/A,#N/A,#N/A,#N/A,6,#N/A}`
Wrapping that in `ISNUMBER` changes the non errors to `TRUE` and the errors to `FALSE`.
`IF` takes that array and in case of `TRUE` (a number) it returns the row number (same indexed range is used).
Then `MAX` returns the largest row number of that array.

*Instead of `FIND` you could also use `SEARCH`. FIND is case sensitive, and SEARCH isn't, further on they operate the same).*

Comment: Thank you so much, this works great. I cant for the life of my figure out how it works but it does. The documentation for find doesn't even say you can use a range. Is that what happening?

Comment: Glad I could help. Edited my answer for further explanation